# Friend function in class defined in namespace

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, friend

I'm trying to make a function in `DataBase` namespace declared in `DataBase.h` file with implementation in `DataBase.cpp` that needs an access to a protected member of `Collection` class.

Here is what i currently have

`Collection.h`:

```
class Collection
{
   ...
protected:
   string name;
   friend Collection& DataBase::getCollection(string name);
};
```

`DataBase.h`:

```
namespace DataBase {
    ...
    Collection& getCollection(std::string collectionName);
}
```

`DataBase.cpp`:

```
namespace DataBase {
    ...
    Collection& getCollection(std::string collectionName)
    {
        for (auto& collection : _collections)
            if(collection.name == collectionName)
            {
               ...
            }
    }

}
```

The problem is I can't access name property.

Comment: Nope, a friend class/function should be able to access even private members.

Comment: `DataBase::getCollection()` uses members of class `Collection` (like `collection.name`), so a definition of that class needs to be visible to the compiler before that point.

Answer (score 0):

You have to forward declare the friend function including namespace. I do not know how you are using `_collections`, so I changed the example a bit and I put everything in one file to start with something that works.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Collection;

namespace DataBase {  
    Collection* getCollection(std::vector<Collection>& collections, std::string collectionName);
}

class Collection
{
protected:
  string name;
  friend Collection* DataBase::getCollection(std::vector<Collection>& collections, std::string name);
};


namespace DataBase {
  Collection* getCollection(std::vector<Collection>& collections, std::string collectionName)
  {
    for (auto& collection : collections)
      if (collection.name == collectionName)
      {
        return &collection;
      }
    return nullptr;
  }
}
```